# Turn off Software Center putting apps in Dock automatically

Tags: 12.04, software-center, dock

In 11.10, when I installed a desktop app it had a check box in the Software Center entry for that app to install it to the Dock right away.  Sometimes I did, sometimes I didn't, depending on how much I planned on using that app.

Now in 12.04 it seems to default to jamming a new icon into the Dock, without asking me and, so far as I can tell, no way to turn it off or revert to the 'old' behavior.

Am I missing something here?  Is there an easy way to turn this 'off'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Open up the Software Centre, click on the View menu and untick New Applications in Launcher.

[image: View > New Applications in Launcher]

Comment: Sweet - simple enough, just not where I would expect to find a setting like that.